# Rails, join 2 tables, show count more than 1 with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm combining 2 tables to see if any car exists at that location but I also would like to combine `where` clause.

```
@country.car_cities.joins(:cars).group("car_cities.id").having("count(cars.id) > 0")
```

This is working just fine. This gets all the cars. But I have a column called `business_model`. I would like to combine with the `cars.where(business_model: @rental_type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining tables, you can place the condition on both sides

```
@country.car_cities.joins(:cars)
  .where(cars: {business_model: @rental_type})
  .group("car_cities.id").having("count(cars.id) > 0")
```

Make sure to check the generated SQL by call `to_sql` which is as you intended.